# Complex NuGet dependency management

Tags: .net, nuget, csproj

I want to provide a NuGet package of a project that I created, but I have some issues "hiding" depencies.

Is the following configuration possible?

- Do not include project references as NuGet dependencies.
- Allow consumers to use code from dependency A.
- Completely hide dependency B from the consumer.

To remove all NuGet dependencies and to hide type B dependencies,  I tried the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- PrivateAssets to remove NuGet depencies -->
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\A.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\B.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)A.dll" />
    <!-- B is hidden, so not included -->
</ItemGroup>
```

The issue is that, at runtime, the internal NuGet code crashes because it cannot find dependency B and its dependencies. (Which is obvious because the DLL is not there.)

Answer (score 0):

`PrivateAssets="All"` really only makes sense when you have a build time dependency to that package.

What you want is to control the flow of assets of B into the project itself. 
Meaning you want to disallow consumers to code against B.

The way to achieve this would be to use `ExcludeAssets="compile"` instead of PrivateAssets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets

So you would have the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\A.csproj"/>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\B.csproj" ExcludeAssets="compile" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This doesn't let me compile. It compiles with PrivateAssets compile, but I'm still left with NuGet dependencies.

Comment: @Aaron https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723880/1399272 is also using PrivateAssets compile.  I agree you still see deps, but the consumer at least can't compile aginst them.  Private compile isn't the same as private runtime; since the latter isn't private, it still copies the private assemblies into output, so you don't get runtime issues loading them.