# How can I hide dependent Nuget packages?

Tags: c#, xml, nuget

I have a class library project file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="InformationLog" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My class library has various public types, such as `PublicClass1`. The Nuget package `InformationLog` has a public type named `Log`. My class library needs `Log` internally to work, but I don't want to make this type visible to users of my class library. I want people to have access to `PublicClass1` but not to `Log` or any of the other types or namespaces in `InformationLog`.

I'm OK with keeping `InformationLog` as a dependency, forcing projects that reference my class library to also use the `InformationLog` nuget package, I just don't want the types in that Nuget package to be visible.

Ideally I would like some XML in my project file to fix this. Something like this:

```
  <PackageReference Include="InformationLog" Version="1.9.0" Access="Private"/>
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: You can't do this.  If your project depends on your class library and that class library depends on a nuget package, then your project also depends on that nuget package.  Unless you have control over that nuget package, there's nothing you can do to limit accessibility in the way you desire.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `PrivateAssets="compile"`.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="InformationLog" Version="1.9.0" PrivateAssets="compile"/>
```

[NuGet's docs on asset selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) has some more details.

You can see that Roslyn, and others, also take advantage of this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/1df5d394195ffcf6aab5b824ae420197ed1f0acc/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzer.Testing/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzer.Testing.csproj#L58-L62

By not making the `runtime` asset private, it means that runtime assets will flow transitively, and the dependency will be copied to apps `bin/` folders and avoid FileNotFound exceptions when your assembly calls APIs on the dependency. But since the `compile` assets are private to your project, they will not flow transitively, and therefore the package consumer will not be able to call APIs on your package's dependencies directly, unless they themselves add a PackageReference to the same package, making it a direct reference, not a transitive package.