How to hide types of a NuGet package
I developed a .NET 8 NuGet package "A", which uses a 3rd party NuGet packages "B", in turn uses the Json.Net(Newtonsoft.Json) package.
"A" -> "B" -> "JSON.NET"

Since NuGet packages are "transitive", so all A's consumers would have access to Json.Net, but this is kind of a pollution because they use System.Text.Json as the JSON library.
"Consumer" -> "A" -> "B" -> "JSON.NET"
    └────────────────────────────┘

So my question is, is there a way to hide or stop exposing types of a NuGet package, in my case, I want to hide types of Json.NET exposing by package B.
And because I can't change B's source, so I can't modify it to use PrivateAssets="all".
UPDATE
I've seen the post "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720292/how-can-i-hide-dependent-nuget-packages", but we are not same.
In that question, the OP is exactly the author of package "B" so he/she can use PrivateAssets="compile" ("all" can also do the trick) in his/her package against "InformationLog", but as I said, I have no rights to change "B"'s source, so I need another way.

"Since NuGet packages are "transitive"" - You are mistaken - NuGet references are not all transitive: NuGet supports private-dependencies (and built/dev-only dependencies) just fine.

Thanks for the info, I mean it's transitive by default .

You don't need to be able to edit ProjectB - just edit ProjectA to make the A->B reference private.

I don't want to hide types of B, my consumers need them, I just want to hide types of Json.Net exposed by B.

Excepting things like Attribute types (e.g.  [JsonProperty]) I can't think of any Json.NET types that would be "exposed" to a downstream referent - and they'd certainly be unusable (and result in a compiler error) if they dereferenced a type/member/etc that required Json.NET type information (because no assembly-reference would be created).

I don't get you, actually in consumer's code,  JsonConvert.Serialize() is usable.

Do you have a public git repo or something so I can take a look?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You are overthinking this, if a third-party library (B) is using another library and it needs for runtime (JSON.NET), then it will break if you would have been able to to "hide" its dependencies, as JSON.NET won't be copied to the final bin folder of (Consumer).
Let alone thinking about version conflicts. Say Consumer is using a different version of JSON.NET with breaking changes, that would turn into a nightmare to figure what is going on, and you can't control what consumers are going to use.
I think what you are looking for is a way to include the final compiled asset in bin, but somehow hide it in Visual Studio, and I don't think that's possible. Something like <PrivateAssets>ide</PrivateAssets>.
Note: Okay, maybe you can compile your package with dependencies natively into a single static DLL (AOT-ed). But that's a different topic, and you are limited as of now where you can use it. Something like how Go does with dependencies.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/

You are right, I want to hide Json.NET at compile time, but let it work as normal at runtime.
